# Search Postgres database for a value, then return its row and table name

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to search my entire Postgres database for a particular value. Once that particular value is found, return the row and table_name where it was found.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109573/search-entire-postgres-database) is similar, but does not have a sufficient answer.

I am open to any solution, using SQL or otherwise.

Comment: Why don't you parse the dump?
1. Make db dump (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html)
2. Parse it using your preferable script language or just open it as a text and make a search.

Comment: Some of these databases are a few GB or more. I'm worried that storing the dump somewhere and grep'ing will be extremely slow

Answer (score 0):

basically all you can do here is write a stored procedure. how can it work? you fetch a list of objects and relevant columns from pg_tables / pg_attribute and do the search one by one. 
this is the only. i don't consider it a good idea to do this kind of stuff at all but if it is necessary for some reason this is the way to go.